# Azure CLI/PowerShell - set automaticOSUpgradePolicy.useRollingUpgradePolicy to true

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cli

I have a virtual machine scale set (VMSS) where I want to set automaticOSUpgradePolicy.useRollingUpgradePolicy = true. If I query the automaticOsUpgradePolicy using this Azure CLI command

```
az vmss show --name myvmssname --resource-group myresourcegroup --query '{"AutomaticOsUpgrades": upgradePolicy.automaticOsUpgradePolicy}'
```

It returns this:

```
"AutomaticOsUpgrades": {
    "disableAutomaticRollback": false,
    "enableAutomaticOsUpgrade": true,
    "useRollingUpgradePolicy": false
}
```

It seems logical that I could set useRollingUpgradePolicy with a similar syntax and object hierarchy...

```
az vmss update --name myvmssname --resource-group myresourcegroup --set upgradePolicy.automaticOSUpgradePolicy.useRollingUpgradePolicy=true
```

But after executing it, it runs for around 10 minutes then throws an error "(InternalOperationError) An internal error occurred in the operation. Code: InternalOperationError Message: An internal error occurred in the operation."

Is my syntax correct? What is the proper PowerShell or Azure CLI execution command?

Note: I am not trying to set `upgradePolicy.mode = Rolling`. I want to set `upgradePolicy.automaticOSUpgradePolicy.useRollingUpgradePolicy = true`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error message `(InternalOperationError)` while trying to upgrade the `VMSS Upgrade Policy` to Automatic using PowerShell or Azure CLI.

Below are steps that can be performed to fix this:

1. Check the network connectivity and ensure that there are sufficient permissions to modify the `VMSS`.
2. then Restart the `VMSS` using the below cmd.

```
 Restart-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -VMScaleSetName "venkat-vmss"
```

[image]

3. Once the above steps are done, try to upgrade the policy using either one way -

**Azure CLI:**

```
 $result= az vmss update --name "venkat-vmss"  --resource-group "v-venkat-mindtree" --set upgradePolicy.automaticOSUpgradePolicy.useRollingUpgradePolicy=true
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Azure Powershell:**

```
Set-AzVmssRollingUpgradePolicy -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>  -VMScaleSetName <name> -UseRollingUpgradePolicy $true
```

Reference: [Restart-AzVmss](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/restart-azvmss?view=azps-10.0.0) & [Set-AzVmssRollingUpgradePolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmssrollingupgradepolicy?view=azps-10.0.0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sourav. I have tried the steps you mentioned including restarting the VMSS, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. I wish I had something more to go off of but the error message "An internal error occurred in the operation" doesn't give any clue as to what the actual problem is